# Difference between .toBe() and .toEqual() - Jasmine Karma testcases

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using Jasmine karma test case for a while and found tests failing sometime because of using .toBe() instead of .toEqual(). What is the difference between **.toBe() and .toEqual()** and when you use these?

Answer (score 4):

- `toBe()` comparison is strict (ex.: `obj1 === obj2` )
   
  **if comparing two objects the identity of the objects is taken in consideration.**
- while `toEqual()` takes only value of the entries in consideration ( it compares object like underscore's `isEqual` method ).

Comment: `toEqual` does not do an `==` check. `toEqual` is comparitively similar to underscores `isEqual` method, it checks for assymetric matches between a and b to start with, it also allows you to give an array of your own custom matching functions as well as checking for inequality between values. https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js check out the `eq` function that `toEqual` uses. This allows for object value matching, array value matching etc.

Comment: @DavidBarker you're right , I simplified the concept a bit too much...

Answer (score 3):

here is an example that explains the difference between both of them

```
describe("Included matchers:", function() {
it("The 'toBe' matcher compares with ===", function() {
var a = 12;
var b = a;

expect(a).toBe(b);
expect(a).not.toBe(null);
});

describe("The 'toEqual' matcher", function() {

it("works for simple literals and variables", function() {
  var a = 12;
  expect(a).toEqual(12);
});

it("should work for objects", function() {
  var foo = {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  };
  var bar = {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  };
  expect(foo).toEqual(bar);
});
});
});
```

you can find more details about other Matchers in the official [website](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, `toBe` is used for comparing strings, boolean values, for example:

```
expect(enabled).toBe(true)
expect(user.name).toBe('Bob')
```

`toEqual` is more suitable for comparing arrays or objects.  For example:

```
expect(myArray).toEqual([1,2,3])
```